# Solving 1D Poisson equation using Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I have been trying to solve the following equation via Green's functions:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x} = \begin{cases}
1, x < \frac{1}{2} \\
0, x > \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}
$$
with boundary conditions $u(0) = u(1) = 0$. The Green's function for this case is given by
$$
G(x, y) = \begin{cases}
x(y-1), x \leq y \\
y(x-1), x \geq y
\end{cases}
$$

I understand that the solution is given by 
$$
u(x) = \int_0^1 G(x, y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
and have tried to subdivide the integral to be able to integrate it:
$\begin{align}
u(x) &= \int_0^x G(x, y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_x^{1/2} G(x, y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{1/2}^1 G(x, y)f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_0^x x(y-1)\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_x^{1/2} y(x-1)\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{1/2}^1 0 \,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{8} - \frac{1}{8}
\end{align}
$

which, while close, is still off by a factor of $-1$. Is there something wrong with the method? I am not certain about how to subdivide the interval. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have substituted the wrong branch of the Green's function on the integral.
Note that when you are integrating $y$ from $0$ to $x$, $y\leq x$ (so $x\geq y)$, so you should use $y(x-1)$ when integrating.
So:
$$
u(x)=\int_0^xy(x-1)dy+\int_x^\frac{1}{2}x(y-1)dy=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3x}{8}
$$
Note that the second derivative of this is 1 and u satisfies only the first boundary condition.
This happens because you should consider the cases $y>\frac{1}{2}$ and $y<\frac{1}{2}$ separately because we don't know the exact value of y (don't know how rigorous this claim is).

The $u(x)$ you have calculated works when $y<1/2$, but if we consider the other case:
$$
u(x)=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}y(x-1)dy+\int_\frac{1}{2}^x0dy+\int_x^10dy=\frac{1}{8}(1-x)
$$
This satisfies the conditions that the other $u$ couldn't.
So:
$$
u(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3x}{8} & x<\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{8}(1-x) & x>\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Hope this helped.